# Palindrome Function (Strings, Stacks, Queues)

Tags: c++, string, function, stack, queue

I am trying to create a Palindrome Function. I have to take a string and place it in a queue, stack. Then compare them to see if they are a palindrome. In my function I have taken out the spaces, converted all letters to lower case and now I am attempting to compare the STACK and the QUEUE to see if the word given is a palindrome. But I cannot do so because of the error message "A value of type void cannot be assigned to an entity of type character." If possible, please show me what I am doing wrong?

```
enter bool isPalindrome(string s){
//lowers all letters to lower case so it will not be case sensetive
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++)
    s[i] = tolower(s[i]);

 //removes white space from the word that is being checked
char c;
int i = 0;
while (s[i])
{
    c=s[i];
    if (isspace(c)) c='\n';
    putchar (c);
    i++;
}

queue<string> q1;
stack<string> s1;
for (int k = 0; k < s.size(); k++) 
    if (isalpha(s[k]))
        q1.push(s);

for (int u = 0; u < s.size(); u++)
    if (isalpha(s[u]))
        s1.push(s);
char e;
char d;
while (q1.size() > 0 )
     e = q1.pop();
     d = s1.pop();
    if (e != d)
        return false;
    else
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`pop()` returns `void`, thus your error. You should first get the value from the container and then `pop` the value out of the container. Note that you should use `top` for `std::stack` and `front` or `back` for `std::queue`

```
e = q1.front();
q1.pop();
d = s1.top();
s1.pop();
```

**EDIT**: Another problem I overlooked is that you are storing whole strings in the queue (and stack) and trying to pop them into char. So what you probably wanted to do is like:

```
std::queue<char>
std::stack<char>
for (int k = 0; k < s.size(); k++) 
    if (isalpha(s[k]))
        q1.push(s[k]);

for (int u = 0; u < s.size(); u++)
    if (isalpha(s[u]))
        s1.push(s[u]);
```

and the same for the stack.

**EDIT2**: Another missing bit is in the last `while`. There should be parenthesis around the loop and the `return true` statement should be after the loop:

```
while (q1.size() > 0 ) {
    e = q1.front();
    q1.pop();
    d = s1.top();
    s1.pop();
    if (e != d)
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: I changed the E, D variables from character to string. But for whatever reason it crashes when I enter a word to be tested.

Comment: Sorry, I saw only the obvious problem and overlooked this. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I suppose I was just frustrated and missed that trivial mistake with the loop. Also, even with your advice, it is failing to compile correctly. It still crashes after inserting a word to be tested.

Comment: Does if fail to compile or does it crash when you run it? If it crashes, how are getting the string to be tested?